# Appending output to a file?

Tags: files

I am developing a custom module and I want to write debugging output to a log file so I can monitor it in real time, and not wait to navigate to watchdog.

I was using `file_save_data()` to write to the public file system, but quickly noticed that it was making `log1.txt`, `log2.txt`, `log3.txt`, etc. I want all my log messages to go into the same file. I looked at the [documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_save_data/7), and saw that the only flags that exist are `FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE`, `FILE_EXISTS_RENAME`, and `FILE_EXISTS_ERROR`. Sadly for me, no `FILE_EXISTS_APPEND`.

What is the drupal way to append data to a file on the file system? Or should I just use native php functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no existing way to append data to an existing file. Only modes you have listed in the question.

You will have to go for native PHP functions (`a` mode in `fopen()` or `FILE_APPEND` in `file_put_contents()`).

**Some pointers:**

Consider using [`hook_watchdog()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_watchdog/7). You can filter what you need to log to the file using the `type` key of the passed array.

Don't forget that there is also a module, `syslog`, to log these watchdog entries to syslog.

You can also use `dd()` function from [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module to easily log specific data to a temp file.

> dd()
>
> Logs any variable to a file named “drupal_debug.txt” in the site’s
>   temp directory. All output from this function is appended to the log
>   file, making it easy to see how the contents of a variable change as
>   you modify your code.
>
> If you’re using Mac OS X you can use the Logging Console to monitor
>   the contents of the log file.
>
> If you’re using a flavor of Linux you can use the command “tail -f
>   drupal_debug.txt” to watch the data being logged to the file.
>
> dd($data, $label = NULL)